# Why Ilist is implementing from both Icollection& Ienumerable,eventhough Icollection:Ienumerable

Tags: c#, interface

Icollection is implemented from Ienumberable(ICollection : IEnumerable),
then why again Icollection &  IEnumerable both are implementing for IList(interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable).

Comment: You are wrong. Can you show a source for your statement?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is incorrect.

[The reference source for `System.Collections.IList`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/ilist.cs) shows that it is defined as

```
public interface IList : ICollection
```

It would have been valid, and would have meant exactly the same thing, if `IEnumerable` had been listed there, but contrary to what your question states, it isn't.

Comment: Sorr hvd,whatever you are saying is not actually expectation.

Comment: @MadhusudhanVIndian Er... What? You did ask why `IList` is defined as `IList : ICollection, IEnumerable` instead of just `IList : ICollection` like you expected, did you not? I think I quite conclusively showed that it *is* defined as just `IList : ICollection`.

Comment: hdv: you are just repeating my question,but not answering ...Sorry for that...
Here am expecting why icollection & ienumerable mentioned instead of only icollection(because icollection:IEnumerable)...

*Please don't mix generics here*

Comment: @MadhusudhanVIndian Again, `IEnumerable` **isn't** mentioned. If it isn't mentioned, asking why it is mentioned is not a sensible question. You're right that I didn't answer the question. I didn't, because the question has no answer.

Comment: @MadhusudhanVIndian To avoid confusion, I've removed the references to the generic versions of `IList<T>` from my answer. Does that help clear things up?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation shows all implemented interfaces for clarification so you can see all the implemented interfaces easily.(I assume that's why you are asking this.)

In the code these two version are equivelant:

```
IList<T> : ICollection<T>

IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
```

Comment: Am not asking based on documentation purpose.Real signature itself like this.
If you say,it just shows all higher level inteface name.Then does it mean it shows for all.?

Answer (score -2):

The ICollection interface extends IEnumerable.

IList is a more specialized interface that extend ICollection.

source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
(see Remarks)

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: I want to clarify that an interface does not implement the methods of another interface but just extends them.

Comment: Nice, but that isn't an answer to his question.

Comment: this isn't an answer to my question